# mysql - WSREP state transfer ongoing

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, galera, mariadb-10.5

I'm using `Galera` for clustring. My OS is ubuntu.

I have 3 nodes:

```
*.30
*.31
*.32
```

---

```
#systemctl status mysql

 mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5.16 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf, override.conf
     Active: activating (start) since Tue 2022-07-05 05:06:33 +0430; 4h 40min ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 244510 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 244511 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 244524 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_re>
   Main PID: 244797 (mariadbd)
     Status: "WSREP state transfer ongoing..."
      Tasks: 10 (limit: 48160)
     Memory: 159.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
             └─244797 /usr/sbin/mariadbd --wsrep_start_position=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1,0-0-0
```

and when I want to login to mysql I got this error:

```
mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)


journalctl -n 200 -u mariadb.service
```

[image]

Comment: This is looking suspicious that after over 4.5hrs its still doing a SST. Can you show the logs of the service (`journalctl -n 200 -u mariadb.service`)?

Comment: @danblack updated my question and added logs.

Comment: Can you add `NotifyAccess=all` in your systemd config (`/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.conf`) (per [MDEV-25887](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25887)) which should clear up the "Got notification..." and potential timeout message in the log. I'm not sure this image is covering the end of the startup logs.